# convert bytes back to list of integers

Tags: python

I have a list of big numbers:

```
[123456, 654321]
```

And I am converting every number to bytes:

```
lst = [(123456).to_bytes(6,'big'), (654321).to_bytes(6,'big')]
>>> [b'\x00\x00\x00\x01\xe2@', b'\x00\x00\x00\t\xfb\xf1']
```

And then I am converting this list into bytes:

```
by = b''.join(lst)
>>> b'\x00\x00\x00\x01\xe2@\x00\x00\x00\t\xfb\xf1'
```

How can I convert back from `b'\x00\x00\x00\x01\xe2@\x00\x00\x00\t\xfb\xf1'` to `[123456, 654321]`?

Comment: This might also be useful: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](/q/312443/4518341) It says "list", but it works on any [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence), including `bytes`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use slicing on byte objects:

```
>>> value = b'\x00\x00\x00\x01\xe2@\x00\x00\x00\t\xfb\xf1'

>>> byte1 = value[:6]
>>> print(byte1)
b'\x00\x00\x00\x01\xe2@'

>>> byte2 = value[6:]
>>> print(byte2)
b'\x00\x00\x00\t\xfb\xf1'
```

Then convert the bytes back into ints:

```
>>> num1 =  int.from_bytes(byte1, byteorder='big')
>>> print(num1)
123456

>>> num2 =  int.from_bytes(byte2, byteorder='big')
>>> print(num2)
654321
```

Then add back into a list:

```
>>> nums = [num1, num2]
>>> print(nums)
[123456, 654321]
```